# Override Mail MailgunTransport class in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-4

Using mailgun as mail driver I am facing the problem that blind carbon copy is not working properly as it shows all the addresses to all the recipients. I found a fix that would solve the problem but it requires to edit the MailgunTransport.php file at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Transport/MailgunTransport.php. I don't want to change a file on vendors folder so I am trying to extend that MailgunTransport class...

I created a folder called app/custom/extensions with two files, CustomMailServiceProvider...

```
<?php namespace custom\extensions;

use Swift_Mailer;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Swift_SmtpTransport as SmtpTransport;
use Swift_MailTransport as MailTransport;
use Illuminate\Mail\Transport\LogTransport;
use custom\extensions\CustomMailgunTransport;
use Illuminate\Mail\Transport\MandrillTransport;
use Swift_SendmailTransport as SendmailTransport;

class CustomMailServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider {

}
```

...and CustomMailgunTransport.php

```
<?php namespace custom\extensions;

class CustomMailgunTransport extends Illuminate\Mail\Transport\MailgunTransport {
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function send(Swift_Mime_Message $message, &$failedRecipients = null)
    {        
        $client = $this->getHttpClient();
        $to = $this->getTo($message);
        $message->setBcc([]);

        $client->post($this->url, ['auth' => ['api', $this->key],
            'body' => [
                'to' => $to,
                'message' => new PostFile('message', (string) $message),
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

CustomMailServiceProvider.php does not redefine any original methods but changes the call from the original MailgunTransport to custom\extensions\CustomMailgunTransport.

I have loaded the app/custom/extensions directory of the new files at composer.json classmap...

```
{
    ...
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            ...
            "app/custom/extensions"                
        ],       
    },
    ...
}
```

And I have swapped the original 'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider' to 'custom\extensions\CustomMailServiceProvider'...

```
'providers' => array(
    ...
    //'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider',
    'custom\extensions\CustomMailServiceProvider',
    ...
),
```

However, at this point I don't know how to call the mail functionalities. If I try to use the Mail facade it uses the original code from MailgunTransport.php

Do I need to create a custom facade? and if so... How can can I do it? Or is there any problem with the code above? Is there any way I could extend only the MailgunTransport.php without creating a CustomMailServiceProvider?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by including the registerMailgunTransport method in the CustomMailServiceProvider and referencing there the new CustomMailgunTransport.

**CustomMailServiceProvider**

```
<?php namespace custom\extensions;

use Swift_Mailer;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Swift_SmtpTransport as SmtpTransport;
use Swift_MailTransport as MailTransport;
use Illuminate\Mail\Transport\LogTransport;
use custom\extensions\CustomMailgunTransport;
use Illuminate\Mail\Transport\MandrillTransport;
use Swift_SendmailTransport as SendmailTransport;

class CustomMailServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider {
/**
 * Register the Mailgun Swift Transport instance.
 *
 * @param  array  $config
 * @return void
 */
    protected function registerMailgunTransport($config)
    {
        $mailgun = $this->app['config']->get('services.mailgun', array());

        $this->app->bindShared('swift.transport', function() use ($mailgun)
        {
            return new CustomMailgunTransport($mailgun['secret'], $mailgun['domain']);
        });
    }
}
```

**CustomMailgunTransport**

```
<?php namespace custom\extensions;

use Swift_Transport;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Swift_Mime_Message;
use GuzzleHttp\Post\PostFile;
use Swift_Events_EventListener;

class CustomMailgunTransport extends \Illuminate\Mail\Transport\MailgunTransport {
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
    */
    public function send(Swift_Mime_Message $message, &$failedRecipients = null)
    {        
        $client = $this->getHttpClient();
        $to = $this->getTo($message);
        $message->setBcc([]);

        $client->post($this->url, ['auth' => ['api', $this->key],
            'body' => [
                'to' => $to,
                'message' => new PostFile('message', (string) $message),
            ],
        ]);
     }
}
```